# Ignore folder before first commit in kdesvn?

Tags: linux, svn, kde-plasma

I have an empty SVN repo on a remote server. I moved the code into `kdesvn` app and now I need to make a first commit. But I want to exclude some folders from commit (ignore them) so that they never upload later on.

How shall I do it in kdesvn? I went to Repository menu but could not find a command to mark folders ignored.

**EDIT**

I did not commit anything yet. Just copied sources into kdesvn. On each file and folder I have icon with a green plus symbol and the status saying "locally added". Look at the image

[image]

Comment: @HemantMetalia What are you asking????

Comment: I just want some tips from you can you please send me a mail so that in reply i can ask my confusion ? you will find my email address from my profile.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make a SVN revert. With kdesvn you select the files to revert, then in the menu `Subversion > Working Copy > Revert current changes`.

If you want to SVN ignore them, just right-click on a file that is not under version control (grey background color) and select `Ignore/Unignore current item`.

Comment: Look at the EDIT pls. I don't have such options and nothing is grey.

Comment: Because you have added the folder. Revert the folder as I described in my first step.

Comment: The repo is empty. I have not committed yet. So I cannon revert as revert option is disabled.

Comment: @sandalone Then use `svn revert` from the command line. But be aware that this will delete your file. Copy them before on a safe place. It is possible that kdesvn does not offer all features of Subversion.